# Most pythonic way to split string into integers

Tags: python, string, integer

I have a string that needs to be validated that it is of the form of ‘#-#’ where the #s should be unsigned integers. What is the most pythonic way to split this into two integers, lo and hi, possibly including type-checking/validation that lo < hi, unsigned ints, and so on?

I’ve thought about various solutions, but I have varying criteria and it must make sure that # and # are unsigned ints with only the one hyphen in between.

Comment: Can you provide some inputs and expected outputs? And also what you have tried.

Comment: What have you tried, and what went wrong with your attempts? Please [edit] to include a [mcve] with a specific description of the problem. `split()`, `map()`, `max()` all seem relevant here but it's hard to offer specific answers without more detail

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is absolutely the **most** pythong way, but I'd split on the `-` character and use a list comprehension to generate `lo` and `hi`:

```py
[lo, hi] = [int(x) for x in s.split('-')]
```

Comment: I thought about this way, but it needs to make sure that the string is not of the form ‘#-#-‘ etc. aka, multiple hypens, and this would interpret them

Answer (score 0):

Best I can think of is using a regular expression to match the exact pattern and `assert` that everything is correct. Note however that doing it this way will crash the program as soon as an invalid input appears, unless you do some extra error handling.

```
import re

input_strings = [
    "123-321",
    "92646-278364",
    # "12345-123",  # error: low > high
    # "123.45-98765",  # error: not integers
]

def get_num_pair(num_str: str):
    m = re.match(r'(\d+)-(\d+)', num_str)
    assert m and len(m.groups()) == 2
    lo, hi = int(m.group(1)), int(m.group(2))
    assert 0 <= lo <= hi
    return lo, hi

for input_str in input_strings:
    print(get_num_pair(input_str))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```py
string = "43-3" #example data
num = string.split("-") #split the string

lo = int(num[0])
hi = int(num[1])

if(lo<hi):
  print("ok")
else:
  print("ko")
```

this will work as long your string is exactly as you told us and there are only unsigned ints in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Mureinik's answer - I'd suggest you do the following:

- use a list comprehension to split the list on `'-'` and turn each bit into `int`s
- carry out validation on the resulting list to ensure it meets your requirements - exactly two elements and the first one is lower
- wrap this in a `try`, `except` block in case the list comprehension gives an error
- wrap *that* in a function that encapsulates the concept of splitting `#-#` strings

e.g.

```py
def parse_twoval_str(twoval_str):
    try:
        vals = [int(s) for s in twoval_str.split("-")]

    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError("Could not parse input - must be of form '123-234'")

    if len(vals) != 2:
        raise ValueError("Input must contain two values")

    a, b = vals

    if a > b:
        raise ValueError("First value must be less than second value")

    return a, b
```

Comment: if anyone would like to explain why an input of `applesauce` results in "invalid literal for int" with "during handling of the exception, another exception occured: could not parse input" I'd like to know - I thought `except ValueError`  would swallow "invalid literal for int"